MongoDB query with $sort takes too long
I have a large mongo collection, when I run {"$and":[{"fieldCheck":"1"},{"timestamp":{"$lt": MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}}]}, the query results the output fast, but when i sort by {timestamp: -1, _id: -1} with the previous filters then the query takes forever.
The collection is indexed with composite index {timestamp: 1, _id: 1}, also fieldCheck is indexed with _id {fieldCheck: 1, _id: 1}
Whats wrong is going on?
I tried indexing mentioned.

What means "large" collection? Are you sure, you get the full output when you do not sort?

Your indices seem leveraged. Have you run explain() to check where is your bottleneck?

The MongoDB query executor can only use a single index for a query.  The predicate {"timestamp":{"$lt": MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}} is equivalent to testing if timestamp is a number, so that will not be very selective.
When there is no sort, the query executor can use the index on {fieldCheck: 1, _id: 1} to select only documents that match {"fieldCheck":"1"}, and then fetch each of those to test the timestamp.  This allow only fetching documents that actually match the query.
When there is a sort stage, the query planner has 2 choices:

use the {"fieldCheck":"1"} index to select documents, and then sort them in memory (in-memory sort is a very heavy process, and usually slow)
use the {timestamp: -1, _id: -1} index to find documents in pre-sorted order, and fetch each one to test the fieldCheck.  While this does not require in-memory sorting, it will require reading nearly the entire collection.

Neither of these options are particularly performant.
If you create an index on {"fieldCheck":1, timestamp: -1, _id: -1}, the query planner will be able to use this one index for both effective document selection and sorting, which should be much faster.
